# Mostrar Thumbnails de uma determinada página wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theme

Estou desenvolvendo um tema para wordpress e criei uma página personalizada, dei o nome do arquivo de page_vans.php quando eu vou criar uma página no dashboard tenho a opção template que aparece para mim escolher e la aparece essa página page_vans.php basicamente oque eu quero simplificando é.

Quero pegar somente as páginas que são criadas e selecionadas com o template da page_vans.php e listas as thumbnails delas no index, se eu fizer um get_page() e listar irão aparecer de todas as páginas, eu queria somente das páginas que estão utilizando o template personalizado (page_vans.php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O template é guardado como uma `meta_value` da página, você pode buscar assim:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type'  => 'page', 
    'meta_query' => array( 
        array(
            'key'   => '_wp_page_template', 
            'value' => 'page_vans.php'
        )
    )
);

$paginas = new WP_Query($args);
```